# Decimal to Binary

Tags: circuit-design, converter

So I've been looking all over the internet for a Decimal to Binary converter but all I've been able to find are Binary to Decimal converters, and Decimal to BCD circuits, does anyone have one?

Comment: Like windows calculator? Or pen-and-paper?

Comment: Without an MCU, it's going to quickly be a mess of logic chips and wires, if you need more than two digits... Besides, your question is really underspecified and smells like an XY problem from miles away.

Comment: I need 3 digits, it's for an 8 bit multiplier

Comment: Have you tried to *design* it rather than look over internet?

Comment: Well I would if I knew how, but I'm only just starting to get intro electronics, and I'm currently learning to understand them

Comment: Then, maybe you can start by making circuits that don't require complex math operations, unless you're willing to include a microcontroller in the design. Just start by making a clock, or a some more basic stuff.

Comment: Where are the 3 digits coming from? Thumb wheels (cheap from China)? Or where, exactly?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please quickly realise that this is not a free design house, homework-answering service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows that you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which your post doesn't, I'm afraid. Please revise your question showing your work and findings so far, in considerable detail. Or delete the question if Internet searches give you your answer anyway. Again, a warm welcome to the site.

Comment: I doubt you have been looking all over the internet, otherwise you should have found the SN74184A.

Comment: @dim: Using a PROM with 12 inputs and 8 outputs like the 2732, it may be done with one IC only and without an MCU.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you'll struggle to find one. The reason for this is that there is no common reason for a BCD to binary converter. Where do the BCD digits come from that you need to convert?

The purpose of the many binary to BCD converter ICs that are around are to support 7-segment displays in the pre-cheap-microcontroller era. You used to use a binary to BCD converter to break out each digit from your ADC or counter, then you would use a BCD to 7-segment driver to run each LED/LCD/VFD display to provide a human readable display of the binary measurement. As you can imagine, this was a rather common function in electronics devices, hence why the chips are readily available.

Without knowing much more about the problem you are trying to solve, your best bet is to use a cheap microcontroller. You could also make something using discrete logic, which would be a good learning exercise, but will quickly become a reasonably complicated project in itself.

Comment: There was a TTL BCD to binary converter, the SN74184A, see [PDF](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheets/400/220358_DS.pdf) datasheet.

Answer (score 2):

As has been pointed out in other answers, you can use the venerable (and I do mean venerable) 74184. Of course, those things have been obsolete for decades, so finding them is .... interesting. If you go on eBay, you can get 20 year old Russian knockoffs for a couple of bucks apiece. You'll need 6 for converting 0 to 255. You'll also need some extra protection logic, since with a 3-digit input there is always the chance that you will inadvertently try to enter a number in excess of 255, and the results of that will not be pretty.

Then, of course, your 6 ICs will draw (worst case) as much as 100 mA each, so you're looking at 600 mA.

Overall, in terms of circuit board size, power dissipation and error resistance, you're much better off programming a 4k x 8 PROM such as a 2732. This comes in a 28 pin DIP, and they are readily available and easily programmed.

Comment: The circuit with 6 ICs 74184 does convert all 3 digit BCD numbers to a correct result with 10 binary bits. The extra protection logic is necessary only if the result should be represented with 8 bits (0 to 255) only.

Answer (score 1):

For a complete 3 digits BCD to binary converter you need 10 output bits for numbers from 0 to 999. 8 bits are good for numbers from 0 to 255.

There was a TTL chip for that purpose, the SN74184A, see this [PDF](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheets/400/220358_DS.pdf) or that [PDF](https://www.utm.edu/staff/leeb/DM74185.pdf) datasheet. On page 6 or 3-736 there is a cascaded circuit using 6 chips for 3 BCD digits input and 10 binary output bits.

If you can't buy the SN74184A, you may program its function table (page 2 or 3-732) into a PROM with 5 inputs and 5 outputs. Of course you may use a PROM with 8 inputs and 8 outputs too. Or you do a single chip solution using a PROM with 12 inputs and 10 outputs. 16 outputs may be used also, just don't use 6 outputs. Or 2 EPROMs with 4096 bytes of 8 bits. Larger EPROMs may be used too.
The least significant bit of the lowest BCD digit needs no processing, therefore a PROM with 11 inputs and 9 outputs will do it too.

Comment: You wouldn't use a PROM these days, you'd use a CPLD.